# Error converting data type nvarchar to bigint in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Why is query #2 giving me an error converting data type nvarchar to bigint?

Query #1:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(AsnNumber AS bigint) AS nvarchar(33)) AS AsnNumber 
FROM [DB1].Schema1.Table1 (nolock)
```

Tried with Convert as well, but get the same error:

```
SELECT Convert(nvarchar(33), Convert(bigint, AsnNumber)) AS AsnNumber 
FROM [DB1].Schema1.Table1 (nolock)
```

Query #2:

```
SELECT AsnNumber
FROM Query1
WHERE AsnNumber = '1777188'
```

Here `AsnNumber` is of type `nvarchar(33)`, null in `Table1`

Comment: Not sure why all the down votes, seems like a reasonable question to me.  Have you tried CONVERT instead of CAST?  If that doesn't work, I can plug it in quick to an actual SQL 2008 instance and help figure it out.

Comment: @Jim No Idea why all the down votes! :S 
I tried Convert as well but it is givng the same error

Comment: Have you checked that all the data in this table is numeric?  Does that first query run without any error?

Comment: @Jim Yes, Query #1 returns data without any errrors

Comment: @Jim Convert giving the same error

Comment: @user793468 On a side note, I would be careful about using (`nolock`) without knowing the downside of it: http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this as an answer, even though it doesn't really answer the question, because I can't fit this properly in a comment.

I ran this against SQL Server 2008 and I don't get any errors..

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @t TABLE(AsnNumber NVARCHAR(33))

  INSERT INTO @t (AsnNumber) VALUES('1777188')
  INSERT INTO @t (AsnNumber) VALUES('1777189')

  SELECT AsnNumber FROM @t

  SELECT CAST(AsnNumber AS BIGINT) as AsnNumber 
  FROM @t
  WHERE AsnNumber = '1777188';

  SELECT CAST(CAST(AsnNumber AS BIGINT) AS NVARCHAR(33)) as AsnNumber 
  FROM @t
  WHERE AsnNumber = '1777188';

  SELECT query1.*
  FROM (SELECT CAST(CAST(AsnNumber AS BIGINT) AS NVARCHAR(33)) as AsnNumber FROM @t) as query1
  WHERE AsnNumber = '1777188';

  WITH query1 (AsnNumber) AS 
  (SELECT CAST(CAST(AsnNumber AS BIGINT) AS NVARCHAR(33)) as AsnNumber FROM @t)
  SELECT AsnNumber FROM query1
  WHERE AsnNumber = '1777188';

END
```

This demonstrates that your query #1 works fine, and it also demonstrates that I can use it as a subquery and I can use it in a common table expression, and still no error.  I have no idea why you're getting an error.

Perhaps you can include a full set of statements to create the table, populate it with data, and then the exact query you're running that produces the error?  If you do that, it would help me to reproduce the issue, and then I could probably explain why it's occurring.  For now, I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: No clue why I get the error... Select without the where clause works... Once I enter the Where AsnNumber = '1777188' it give the error. And AsnNumber column does not contain any invalid data and is of type nvarchar(33)